# how to prove the smallest singular value of a matrix is no smaller than the minimal eigenvalue of its symmetric part?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Let A be a real square matrix. How to show that $\lambda_{min}((A^TA)^{\frac{1}{2}})\geq \lambda_{min}(
(A+A^T)/2)$? Here, $\lambda_{min}()$ denotes the minimal eigenvalue of a Hermitian matrix.

Comment: What happens if you square $(A+A^T)/2$?